# Python output line wrapping

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion

I am running the following Python script in an OS X 10.8 terminal with a line length of about 200 characters. However the output from the script is wrapped at about line 80.
How can I make the output lines continue until the console's length?

Here is my Python script:

```
import csv as csv 
import numpy as np
#Open up the csv file in to a Python object
csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('./data/train.csv', 'rb')) 
header = csv_file_object.next()  #The next() command just skips the 
                                 #first line which is a header
data=[]                          #Create a variable called 'data'
for row in csv_file_object:      #Run through each row in the csv file
    data.append(row)             #adding each row to the data variable
data = np.array(data)            #Then convert from a list to an array
#Be aware that each item is currently a string in this format
for datum in data:
    print datum[0:10]
```

The output I get is like:

```
['1' '3' 'Najib, Miss. Adele Kiamie "Jane"' 'female' '15' '0' '0' '2667'
 '7.225' '']
['0' '3' 'Gustafsson, Mr. Alfred Ossian' 'male' '20' '0' '0' '7534'
 '9.8458' '']
```

Comment: This is most certainly a parameter of the terminal you need to set. Python doesn't care about the width of your terminal window. It just prints.

Comment: It's a setting of numpy's `array` representation, to have it the whole line just print every "datum" yourself with `str.join`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: No, it is not.  The terminal does not pretty print the array because of some terminal setting.

Comment: If I use cat for the same file it fills the entire line and the column setting is 203

Comment: @Gandaro: Oh, that's interesting. Thanks.

Comment: ok, print ",".join(datum) now takes the entire line. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a setting of numpy's array representation, to have it the whole line, you would have to  print every `datum` yourself with `str.join`.